# CSS or SASS How to change style of ::after, ::before effects of parent element when child element is active

Tags: html, css, sass

html

```
   <div class="styled-select-box">
     <select class="styled-select">
       <option value="20">20</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

css, I should change the style of *.styled-select-box::after* when *.styled-select* is *:active* or *:focus*

```
.styled-select-box::after {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url(/custom-icons/arrow-down.svg);
  background-size: 12px 12px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 16px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-position-y: 6px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.styled-select:active *parentElement* {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

[image: I tried with :has() but it not supported by browsers]

**I tried with :has() but it not supported by browsers**

Comment: no, i can't change style of ::after effect

Comment: By child element (select-box) is active you mean when all options are visible or when an option is selected?

Comment: when select is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: You can find some workarounds here. Its planned to have a :has pseudo class:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: div:has(> select) not supported by browsers